# Python - Never Ending While Loops caused by a Definition

Tags: python, function, while-loop, boolean

I'm currently making a main menu for my scoring system that will take the user to different parts of code by using while loops as a simple form of validation but it causes a never ending while loops because some of my definition also have while loops as well. Here's what I've done

```
def menu():
 print("""\n Main Menu \n
 1) Join the Event as a Team
 2) Join the Event by Yourself
 3) Score Screen""")

 menuchoice_option = ["1","2","3"]

 menuchoice = ""

 while menuchoice not in menuchoice_option:
  menuchoice = input("Please enter your choice here:")

 if menuchoice == "1":
  team_menu()
  menuchoice = True
 elif menuchoice == "2":
  individual()
  menuchoice = True
 elif menuchoice == "3":
   #scorescreen()
   menuchoice = True
 else:
   menuchoice = False
   print("Please enter a value between 1-3")
   menuchoice = input("Please enter your choice here:")
```

Here's my other functions that the menu def causes to do an infinite whille loops

```
def team_menu():

 global teamS
 team_player = ""
 while team_player != "":
  team_player = input("What is your name:")
  print("""\n Available Teams \n
  1) Team Ahab
  2) Team Ishmael
 \n 3) Go back to Main Menu\n""")

 team_choice = ""
 team_choice_option = ["1","2","3"] # all valid choices on team menu

 while team_choice not in team_choice_option:
  team_choice = input("Enter your choice here:")

 if team_choice == "1":
  teamS["Team 1"]["Team Ahab"].append(team_player)
  print(teamS["Team 1"])
  print("Thank You for Joining Team Ahab")
  team_choice = True

 elif team_choice == "2":
 teamS["Team "+ team_choice]["Teeam Ishmael"].append(team_player)
 print(teamS["Team 2"])
 print("\nThank You for Joining Team Miller\n")
 team_choice = False

elif team_choice == "3":
 menu()
 team_choice = True

else:
 print("Enter a value between 1-3")
 team_choice = False
```

My ideal output would be for it stop causing infinite while loops from different defs in my code. I'm a beginner so please execuse me

Comment: We'd also have to see your functions that cause the infinite loops to help

Comment: Your `menuchoice` is the string that the user inputs; then you overwrite that with `menuchoice = True`. Not sure what the idea behind that is.

Comment: If you call `menu()` again in `team_menu` or `individual` you do something wrong.

Comment: Are you running your code in a Python 3 or Python 2 interpreter? What happens if you type `"1"` (with the quotes) at your input prompt? The `input()` function works very differently in Python 2. I can only reproduce your problem with a Python 2 interpreter.

Comment: Use a different variable for the boolean values

Comment: I did use ```menu()``` on my other defs so it can return the use to the main menu if they want to

Comment: I do want tp put my other functions to show you guys the issue but I am afraid my example would be too long and idk if that's allowed here

Comment: What happens if you (over)simplify the definition of `menu()` by deleting everything after the `while` loop?

Comment: it takes me to my other function but without causing the infinite loop problem

Comment: How would it take you to another function? If you did the oversimplification, then `menu()` should finish right after you input something within `menuchoice_option`.

Comment: @paul-atreidis all of your recent questions looks like you start learning programming and they arise from misunderstanding of basic architecture and some sort of the callback hell. I recommend you to start from reading about finite sate automata principles for your menus, pure functions without side-effects and avoiding of globals.

Comment: @jjramsey Misread your comment so I answered your question wrongly. After I removed all the stuff under the while loop it led me to my ``` team_menu()``` for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old:

> Well... `True` will never be one of your `menuchoice_option`, they are `1,2,3`.
> Make `menuchoice="1"` (instead of `True`), for example, if the user select `"1"`.

**Edit**:

Try to simplify your code: ideally, data should be atomic, and code should work around the data to extract and act as best/smart as possible. And use a better indentation (helps seeing the blocks).
Something like the following would be much, much better to maintain/develop:

```py
def menu():
  options = {
    1: "Join the Event as a Team",
    2: "Join the Event by Yourself",
    3: "Score Screen"
  }

  funcs = {
    1: team_menu,
    2: individual,
    3: scorescreen
  }

  print("\n Main Menu \n")
  for k,v in options.items():
    print(f"{k}) {v}")

  choice = None
  while choice not in options:
    # notice that if a value invalid for "int()" casting, 
    # the code will blow. Wrap this with try/except to avoid it.
    choice = int(input("Please enter your choice here:"))

  # By now, you know a valid option was chosen.
  # Let's use to select the corresponding function from "funcs" dict
  funcs[choice]()
```

***I did not test it. But looks like working.***

Comment: While that would be a good idea, it wouldn't stop the infinite loop problem, since the `while` loop occurs *before* `menuchoice` is assigned a Boolean value.

Comment: @jjramsey right...looking carefully now, I actually don't where the infinite loop comes from. Unless he is calling `menu` in some child function, after `while` if surpassed I don't see a loop...anyhow, that's it, I gave my 2 cents here. Hopefully I helped somebody improving their Python code. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation but what I meant by a infinite loop is that after I go through one def with while loops it lead me to another one with while loops thus exaplains what I meant by a "infinite loop" @jjramsey

Comment: @Brandt Tried your code and it worked! Thanks for that man! What does ```for k,v in options.items():
    print(f"{k}) {v}")``` do exactly?

Comment: Good @PaulAtreidis, I'm glad it helped. If you judge that's a "right answer" to your problem, make it so. To understand those lines, have a look at Python dictionary `items()` method, and (regarding _print_) look for for Python "F-strings".

Comment: @Brandt sorry to bother you again but what does ```funcs[choice]()``` do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

How about using some recursion for the menu, I share my idea:

```py
options = """
Main Menu

 1) Join the Event as a Team
 2) Join the Event by Yourself
 3) Score Screen
 4) Exit

>>> """

def menu(menuchoice):
    if menuchoice == "1":
        team_menu()
    elif menuchoice == "2":
        individual()
    elif menuchoice == "3":
        #scorescreen()
        pass
    elif menuchoice == "4":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Please enter a value between 1-5")
        decision = str(input(">>> "))
        menu(decision)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    decision = str(input(options))
    menu(decision)
```

I hope I give you an idea.